# How to run algorithms on IBMQ via Qiskit-Aqua?

Tags: programming, qiskit, ibm-q-experience, optimization

I am trying to run an optimization problem on IBMQ. Running the same code on QASM simulator works fine. However, changing only the backend name to IBMQX takes long time. I am aware of the queues although, there is no way to track the status of my job. I have followed the same code structure given on qiskit-aqua partition example tutorial. 
Any help would be really appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Here is tested code (also provided in one of the qiskit tutorials)

```
lapse = 0
interval = 60
while not job.done:
    print('Status @ {} seconds'.format(interval * lapse))
    print(job.status)
    time.sleep(interval)
    lapse += 1
print(job.status)
```

where interval is giving in seconds (if your job requires longer waiting and execution, I would suggest to increase it). This will provide you information about your queue placement.

Answer (score 2):

There is currently no way to check the status of a job in Qiskit Aqua:

https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-aqua/issues/545

However, it looks like it is a feature that is coming.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what is your definition of "long time" the answer might be different:

- If it is of the order of minutes, then you can't do anything and you just have to wait for your turn in the queue.
- If it is several days, then there might be a problem (or a very very long queue).

Anyway, you **can** track the status of your job, even if this status does not include its position within the queue. Here is a (non-tested) example:

```
# Setup everything for Qiskit.
# Create your quantum program
job = qiskit.execute(my_circuits, the_backend)
# Ask for the status
print(job.status()) # will return one of the values listed here:
                    # https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-terra/blob/master/qiskit/backends/jobstatus.py
```